# How to include DiagrammeR/mermaid flowchart in a Rmarkdown file

Tags: r, r-markdown, diagrammer, mermaid

I have an R markdown file:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Me"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```
## R Markdown
This is an R Markdown document.
````

As well as a DiagrammeR/mermaid chart:

```
graph LR
    A-->B
```

How can I add the chart in the R-markdown?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Actually it is trivial:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Me"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```
## R Markdown
This is an R Markdown document. 

```{r}
library(DiagrammeR)
mermaid("
graph LR
    A-->B
")
```
````

Comment: This works well for me if the output format is HTML, but not if PDF/LaTex. Would you have any suggestions?

Comment: If you know of any answer for LaTex/PDF, thank you for adding it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60336847/diagrammer-mermaid-flowchart-in-rmarkdown-file-with-output-format-pdf-latex