# Which knitr hooks are invoked when a DiagrammeR graph is rendered in rmarkdown?

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, diagrammer

I have an RMarkdown document where I use `data.tree` and `DiagrammeR` to generate models. I then display these using a set-up similar to the one used in [How to include DiagrammeR/mermaid flowchart in a Rmarkdown file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40803017/how-to-include-diagrammer-mermaid-flowchart-in-a-rmarkdown-file)

For example:

````
```{r fig.cap="Structureel model bij enkelvoudige regressie.", fig.with=4, fig.height=1}

drawStructuralModel <- function(covariates, criterion) {
  ### Create tree
  res <- Node$new(criterion);
  for (covariate in covariates) {
    res$AddChild(covariate);
  }
  ### Set display settings
  SetEdgeStyle(res, dir='back');
  res <- ToDiagrammeRGraph(res, direction = "descend");
  res <- add_global_graph_attrs(res, "layout", "dot", "graph");
  res <- add_global_graph_attrs(res, "rankdir", "RL", "graph");

  ### Draw and return tree
  render_graph(res);
}

drawStructuralModel("X", "Y");

```
````

So far so good. The caption text is added, which is what you'd expect.

Except :-)

Above, in the 'setup' knitr chunk, I used `setFigCapNumbering` from `userfriendlyscience` (see https://github.com/Matherion/userfriendlyscience/blob/master/R/setFigCapNumbering.R). This function uses `knit_hooks$set` to set a hook for plots, so that the captions are automatically numbered.

But this numbering isn't applied to the `DiagrammeR` output.

I guess that makes sense, since it's not actually a plot, rather an HTML widget or some SVG or so. I would still *like* it to be numbered as a figure, though.

But how do I find out which hook `knitr` invokes when `DiagrammeR` output is generated?

I could always resort to using the more generic 'automatic caption' function `setCaptionNumbering` (https://github.com/Matherion/userfriendlyscience/blob/master/R/setCaptionNumbering.R), and tell it to use the same counter option as the figure caption thingy uses. That would sidestep the issue, but I'd prefer to modify the appropriate `knitr` hook.

And since this problem (figuring out which hook `knitr` uses for output produced by a given function) probably occurs more often, I thought it would be worth opening an SA question.

Does anybody know how you can find this out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`knitr` calls `knit_print` on the output produced by a given chunk. This then calls the appropriate method based on the class of the output. You can find out what methods are available by running `methods("knit_print")`, then see if any of those match the class of the output from DiagrammeR.

Looking at your example, I'm guessing the class of your output is `"DiagrammeR" "htmlwidget"`, so knitr is calling `knit_print.htmlwidget`.

Digging into that source code, it calls `htmltools::knit_print.html`, which wraps the tags and then outputs asis. So to answer your question, it uses the default hooks for asis output in whatever output format you're using.